# View controller not being created

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a navigation controller that starts my app (`rootViewController` is the `navigationController`). Then inside one of the views of the navigation I call:

```
TabBarController *tab = [[TabBarController alloc] init];

// Presentation
[self presentViewController:tab animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Then one of the tabs calls the `UIImagePickerController` and then saves the image on another thread. Then I return to the main queue and run:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        PostViewController *post = [[PostViewController alloc] init];

        // Presentation
        [self presentViewController:post animated:NO completion:nil];
    });
```

But the post view never gets called and the `viewDidLoad` never gets hit in the `PostViewController.m`.  Instead the `imagePicker` disappears and returns to the `tabBarController`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try to present post inside the completion block of picker dismissViewControllerAnimated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you PostViewController object is not nil , Present the view controller after the dismiss process of picker ViewController is completed . Try this Code

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

     PostViewController *post = [[PostViewController alloc] init];

    // Presentation
    [self presentViewController:post animated:NO completion:nil];
}];

});
```

Comment: But for a split second it shows the tab bar controller and how do I make that disappear?